# Hide PyQt app from taskbar

Tags: python, widget, pyqt4

I'm a beginner in PyQt. I was trying to create a simple app to try some of the toolkit's many features. My question is, how can I hide the app icon from the taskbar? 
I don't want the user to be able to see the icon in taskbar and to minimize it using this icon. Is there any window flags that I can use to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PyQt4 Minimize to Tray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758256/pyqt4-minimize-to-tray)

Comment: @katrielalex: I think he means the taskbar icon and not the tray icon.

Comment: @PulpFiction: yes; the way you "minimise to tray" is to hide the taskbar icon and make a tray icon.

Comment: @katrielalex Yes, I meant hiding the taskbar icon, while the app is still not minimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from [this thread](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/8902):

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = QWidget()

    mainWindow = QMainWindow(widget)
    mainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 14):

This should do the trick:

```py
myApp.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Tool)
```

Answer (score 2):

This drove me nuts for days.  Complete app code to implement below.

Key bits:

- override closeEvent(), enabling it to do either of just hiding window
  or true exit
- create some facility for user to choose either hide or
  exit behavior
- don't show() main window on instantiation, just exec_() the App

> ```
> import sys
> from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction, QApplication, QFrame, QIcon, \
>     QMainWindow, QMenu, QSystemTrayIcon
> from PyQt4.QtCore import SIGNAL
>
> class MyApp(QMainWindow):
>     def __init__(self, parent, title):
>         super(QMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
>         self.exitOnClose = False
>         exit = QAction(QIcon(), "Exit", self)
>         self.connect(exit, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.exitEvent)
>         self.trayIcon = QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon(), self)
>         menu = QMenu(self)
>         menu.addAction(exit)
>         self.trayIcon.setContextMenu(menu)
>         self.connect(self.trayIcon, \
>             SIGNAL("activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)"), \
>             self.trayIconActivated)
>         self.trayIcon.show()
>         self.trayIcon.showMessage("MyApp is running!", "Click to open window\nRight click for menu" )
>
>     def trayIconActivated(self, reason):
>         if reason == QSystemTrayIcon.Context:
>             self.trayIcon.contextMenu().show()
>         elif reason == QSystemTrayIcon.Trigger:
>             self.show()
>             self.raise_()
>
>     def closeEvent(self, event):
>         if self.exitOnClose:
>             self.trayIcon.hide()
>             del self.trayIcon
>             event.accept()
>         else:
>             self.hide()
>             event.setAccepted(True)
>             event.ignore()
>
>     def exitEvent(self):
>         self.exitOnClose = True
>         self.close()
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     app = QApplication(sys.argv)
>     myapp = MyApp(None, "My System Tray App")
>     app.exec_()
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend trying to hide an application's taskbar presence, especially if the application is visible. If you are only trying to prevent minimizing from the taskbar then you can achieve this by creating your top level widget with the following window flags like this:

```
QWidget *mainWindow = new QWidget(0, Qt::CustomizeWindowHint 
    | Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint 
    | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint);
```

If you don't want a maximize flag, you can leave that one out of the list too.

The various window flags that Qt can use are documented [here (Qt::WindowFlags)](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qt.html#WindowType-enum).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on **Ubuntu with Unity** and want to hide an application's icon from the launcher on the left-hand-side, you will probably need `Qt.SplashScreen`. This worked for me but I don't remember if I also needed `Qt.Tool`, which is enough on Windows. For the SplashScreen attempt you may have to reimplement the resize functionality as it disables this feature of a QStatusBar (that has a SizeGrip) for example.

[Here](https://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-examples/source/1b711e0113be01a061328f387bd8ec201eb47db8%3aexamples/widgets/windowflags.py) is a little example to try out window flags.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialise your main window like this `self.setWindowFlags(Qt.ToolTip)`

Answer (score 0):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # this will hide the app from task bar

        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.Tool)

        self.setGeometry(60, 60, 800, 500)

        # creating a label widget
        # by default label will display at top left corner
        self.label_1 = QLabel('no task bar', self)

        # moving position
        self.label_1.move(100, 100)

        # show all the widgets
        self.show()
```