# Multi-window QT app without taskbar entry

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, pyside6

I'm developing a note application with PySide6 on Ubuntu 22.04. The note windows should be like usual windows, but they should have no taskbar entry.

I tried already multiple approaches, including the answers from [Hide PyQt app from taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4044994/7410886). It seems they are fine for single window apps, but have some caveats for multi window apps. Here is how far I got:

```py
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *

class NoteWindow(QFrame):
    i = 1

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Tool)
        self.setWindowTitle(str(self.i))
        NoteWindow.i += 1
        self.show()

app = QApplication([])
w1 = NoteWindow()
w2 = NoteWindow()

# close the app after 10 seconds
close_timer = QTimer()
close_timer.singleShot(10000, app.quit)

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

There is no taskbar entry, but the second window is **always** in front of the first one. I would like to have the clicked window in front (I think this is the usual window behavior).

Do you have any ideas? Ideally it should work cross-platform.

Comment: I'm not a python guy, so I don't fully understand your example, but could this be at least part of the problem? From the docs:  If there is a parent, the tool window will always be kept on top of it.

Also, have you looked at Qt::FramelessWindowHint?

Comment: Both windows don't have a parent. So in theory it shouldn't matter. Just to make sure, I tried with an explicit parent, with the same result.

I'm using `Qt::FramelessWindowHint`, but in another context. It hides the titlebar. So it doesn't have an effect on this particular problem. I tried `Qt::BypassWindowManagerHint`, too. It resolved the "internal" ordering problem, but then the note windows were on top of everything else always.

FTR: [windowtype doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#WindowType-enum)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qt Hide Taskbar Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055506/qt-hide-taskbar-item)

Comment: Unfortunately no. I will try to add all tried approaches to the question. After reading [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055506/qt-hide-taskbar-item#comment111774836_4056292), I fear that tinkering with X11 is necessary to get it to work on my machine.

Comment: What do you mean by _There is no taskbar entry, but the second window is always in front of the first one. I would like to have the clicked window in front (I think this is the usual window behavior)._
I tried both your scripts and I got practically the same result: No taskbar, one window upon the other, but when shifted away I can select either of the two. I'm not understading the point

Comment: @Buzz: The point is: When the windows are overlapping and you click at one of them, it should come to front. This doesn't work for me _on Ubuntu 22.04_. On windows, the script mentioned in the question works.

Comment: Sorry @Marph, I missed the OS you were working on

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments, I was able to get it to work on my machine:

```py
import shutil
import subprocess
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *

class NoteWindow(QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        if shutil.which("xprop") is not None:
            # Workaround to get multiple windows without task bar on X11.
            subprocess.check_call([
                "xprop",
                "-f", "_NET_WM_STATE", "32a",
                "-id", str(self.winId()),
                "-set", "_NET_WM_STATE", "_NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR",
            ])
        self.show()

app = QApplication([])
w1 = NoteWindow()
w2 = NoteWindow()

# close the app after 10 seconds
close_timer = QTimer()
close_timer.singleShot(15000, app.quit)

app.exec()
```

However, messing around with the window manager is not nice and not cross-platform. Maybe there is a better way, so I'm leaving the question open.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of open source! Window managers just *exist*: they *may* follow the known implementation, but there's no guarantee that they'll actually do it. Their behavior may be inconsistent or not "generally" accepted. You can only live with it and: 1. test using VMs (hoping that different versions of the same WM doesn't implicate inconsistency); 2. hope other WM you didn't consider don't override the "requested" behavior. The real question you should probably try to ask is: what is the *actual* order those windows should respect? And how that should be triggered?

Comment: It was necessary to use `str(self.winId().__int__())` in PyQt5, since the `repr()` output is just `<sip.voidptr object at 0x7ff184b813f0>`.