# PyQt4: self.hide() only hide the content

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

I tried to to subclass QMainWindows and make a call to self.hide() when the minimize event was caught. When I pressed the minimize button, it is minimized to taskbar, and when I pressed it at the taskbar so that it appear again on the screen, I found that it is not invisible. Only the content of the QMainWindows is hide and the frame is still there.

Is it what self.hide() supposed to behave?

I want to make it minimize to system tray, but many of the answers I found from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/758256/248296) didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to to subclass QMainWindows and make a call to self.hide()
>   when the minimize event was caught. When I pressed the minimize
>   button, it is minimized to taskbar, and when I pressed it at the
>   taskbar so that it appear again on the screen, I found that it is not
>   invisible. Only the content of the QMainWindows is hide and the frame
>   is still there.
>
> Is it what self.hide() supposed to behave?

I believe that's the correct behaviour. When you do `self.hide()` you are not hiding the **window** (as suggested in the accepted answer of the linked question) but the widget in it. That's why when you do restore you see the frame, but not the widget.

In your linked question see the other answers and try them - there are code samples.

UPDATE:

Here is a working example from you linked question (tested in KDE with Python 2.7):

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore 
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QFormLayout,QSystemTrayIcon

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()     
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):               
        self.icon = QSystemTrayIcon()
        r = self.icon.isSystemTrayAvailable()
        print r 
        self.icon.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(':/trolltech/styles/commonstyle/images/networkdrive-16.png'))
        self.icon.show()
        #self.icon.setVisible(True)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(':/trolltech/styles/commonstyle/images/networkdrive-16.png'))          
        self.setWindowTitle('Message box')    
        self.show()
        self.icon.activated.connect(self.activate)
        self.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):

        reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message', 
                    "Are you sure to quit?\n(choose No to minimize to tray, and double click to restore)", 
                    QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()    
        else:
            self.icon.show()    
            self.hide()
            event.ignore()

    def activate(self, reason):
        print reason 
        if reason == 2:
            self.show()

    def __icon_activated(self, reason):
        if reason == QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.DoubleClick:
            self.show()   

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: In the related question, the accepted answer suggested to call self.hide() in order to "hide to tray", but that only move the windows to taskbar, thus I don't see why this approach works.